# Xamarin.Forms AppResources: When localizing, how to "look up" the default language translation at runtime

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization

I have an XF app that I'm trying to provide multiple languages for using resx/AppResources files. However, I have a need to be able to access the English (default language values) at runtime for logging purposes. Basically the app has Activities that the user can complete. Each activity has a title that is translated. When an activity is completed by the user I want to log it too my server so I can see which activities are being used the most. Obviously I'd rather not log the Chinese titles.

What are the best way(s) I can retrieve the default language values regardless of what the App's current language is set to?

Regards,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

On Android:

```
Locale.Default.GetDisplayLanguage(Locale.Default)
```

On IOS:

```
var te = NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier;
```